# React helmet inserting Scripts at end of rendered code

Tags: reactjs, react-helmet

When i test my page in "Google Structured data testing tool" I find this at end of my code.
I am also sharing my component where data is being inserted in helmet:

```
   <!-- Inserted by webpack:///../node_modules/react-helmet/lib/HelmetUtils.js? -->
       <script type="application/ld+json">
       </script>
   <!-- Inserted by webpack:///../node_modules/react-helmet/lib/HelmetUtils.js? -->
      <script type="application/ld+json">
      </script>
```

Please find the code below where data is inserted in helmet:

```
export const structuredDataSingle = (props) => {
  const arr = [];
  const {
    location: {
      pathname
    },
  } = props;
  const pathnames = pathname.split('/').filter(x => x);
  if(pathnames.length <= 1) {
    return JSON.stringify({
      "@context": "https://schema.org/",
      "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
      "itemListElement": [{
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 1,
        "name": "Home",
        "item": `${BASE_URL}`
      }, {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 2,
        "name": props.title || props.pageTitle,
        "item": `${BASE_URL}/${pathnames[0]}`
      }]
    })
  }
  else{
    return JSON.stringify({
      "@context": "https://schema.org/",
      "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
      "itemListElement": [{
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 1,
        "name": "Home",
        "item": `${BASE_URL}`
      }, {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 2,
        "name": props.title || props.pageTitle,
        "item": `${BASE_URL}/${pathnames[0]}`
      }, {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 3,
        "name": props.title || props.pageTitle,
        "item": `${BASE_URL}/${pathnames[0]}/${pathnames[1]}`
      }]
    })
  }
};

const MetaTag = (props) => {
  // console.log(props,'**********')
  const baseUrl = SHARING_URL;
  const noIndexDisabled= props.match.params.href === 'understanding-psychedelic-therapy-5186' 
  || props.match.params.href === 'understanding-psychedelic-therapy-5186/7216' 
  || props.location.pathname === ROUTE.WHY 
  || props.location.pathname === ROUTE.PRIVACY_POLICY 
  || props.location.pathname === ROUTE.TERMS 
  || props.location.pathname === ROUTE.ACCEPTABLEUSE 
  || props.location.pathname === ROUTE.SUPPORT 
  || props.location.pathname === ROUTE.HOME_P
  || props.location.pathname === ROUTE.HOME_H
  || props.location.pathname === ROUTE.LEGAL 
  || props.location.pathname === ROUTE.HOME || NODE_ENV != 'production' ? false : true;
  const href = `${BASE_URL}${props.location.pathname}`;
  const title= props.pageTitle ? props.pageTitle : props.ogTitle;
  const url= props.url ? props.url : href
  return (<Helmet>
    <title>{props.pageTitle}</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content={title} />
    <meta property="og:image" content={(props || {}).image} />
    <meta property="og:url" content={url} />
    <meta property="og:type" content={(props || {}).type}></meta>
    <meta property="og:description" content={(props || {}).description} />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content={props.ogWidth || "1200"} />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content={props.ogHeight || "630"} />
    <meta name="description" content={(props || {}).description} />
    {/* {
      !(JSON.stringify(props.match.params) === '{}' && NODE_ENV === 'production') && (
        <meta name="robots" content="-index, -follow" />)
    } */}
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="@dssd" />
    <meta name="twitter:title" content={props.pageTitle} />
    <meta name="twitter:image" content={props.image} />
    <meta name="twitter:description" content={props.description} />
    <meta name="twitter:app:name:iphone" content={props.appName} />
    <meta name="twitter:app:id:iphone" content="1540109137" />
    <meta name="twitter:app:url:iphone" content={props.appURL} />
    <meta name="twitter:app:name:googleplay" content={props.appName} />
    <meta name="twitter:app:id:googleplay" content='com.h.podcast' />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <meta name="facebook-domain-verification" content="8x06v66qga8w4c2ibizdz5i1lghaj6" />
    {noIndexDisabled && <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />}
    <link rel="canonical" href={href} />
    {
      ![
        ROUTE.HOME,
        ROUTE.WHY_H
      ].includes(props.location.pathname) && (
        <script type="application/ld+json" data-react-helmet="true">{structuredDataSingle(props)}</script>
      )
    }
    {
      props.markup && (
        <script type="application/ld+json" data-react-helmet="true">{JSON.stringify({
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "@type": props.markup.type,
          "@id": props.markup.id,
          ...props.markup,
          "type": undefined,
          "id": undefined,
        })}</script>
      )
    }
    { <script type="application/ld+json" data-react-helmet="true" data-rh="true">
        {
          JSON.stringify({
            "@context": "https://schema.org",
            "@type": "Organization",
            "brand": {
              "@type": "Brand",
              "name": "klk",
            },
            "contactPoint": {
              "@type": "ContactPoint",
              "email": "ewe@gmail.com"
            },
            "email": "wew@gmail.com",
            "founder": {
              "@type": "Person",
              "givenName": "ahj"
            },
            "foundingDate": "2020-01-11",
            "legalName": "Hk",
            "location": "India",
            "logo": `${baseUrl}/public/assets/fullLogo.png`,
            "url": `${baseUrl}`
          })
        }
      </script>
      }
  </Helmet>);
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you show your react component code where you might have imported react-helmet ?

Comment: @TheRakeshPurohit I have shared the component,Please help!

Comment: where is the ```<structuredDataSingle />``` is called ?

Comment: It is being called from this code itself, check the script tag below in the code, Just global search this, you will find it

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are still in trouble but I had the same problem and I just found the solution. In my case the problem was a hydrated variable within a string, (like this `${process.env.METADATA_URL}/${data.slug}`) which at the first turn of rendering was set undefined and then inserted by webpack at the bottom of the html file. Once I found another way to set it, the problem was solved.

I hope it was helpful.